# Dealing with answers containing ad hominem statements

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, etiquette

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7322117) to remove an ad hominem statement from an otherwise good answer. Oddly, it was rejected, because my change "deviates from the original intent of the post".

I don't see at all how removing a statement that does not add anything of meaningful value to the answer changes the original intent, unless you'd argue that the original intent included insulting.

So my question is, is it right to remove ad hominem statements from answers, especially considering that many people will not accept such an answer? If not, is it acceptable for an answer to contain ad hominem statements?

Comment: I'm reluctant to say that this answer was worth editing in the first place.  The question itself is off-topic, and the answer dives on the subjective side.

Comment: Honestly, it does look like the original intent is to insult. I mean I hate SEO fanatics as much as the next guy (just look at the comments on the answer), but I'm sure there are better ways to express that sentiment. Yet, it's not the sort of thing that would warrant an "offensive" flag. I dunno...

Comment: I'm not asking about an offensive flag, and maybe the linked question is not the best example. I still don't have an answer and I don't see what's wrong with my question (3 downvotes, really?)

Comment: nitpick, but that's not an ad hominem attack.  It's not saying that someone else is wrong because of some trait of that person outside of the argument.  It's just an insult (not used as an argument to support some conclusion).

Comment: @Servy What makes you think I'm talking about an _argumentum_ ad hominem?

Comment: Additionally, using a term like "charlatan" isn't *just* an insult.  It's an actual trait that can accurately describe a person or group of people, it just has a negative connotation (rightly so) in society.  This post is doing a pretty decent job of supporting the assertion that the trait accurately describes the group in question, and makes a case for why it's important that you know the information (it's not just an insult for the sake of being insulting).

Comment: Describing someone as a criminal or a terrorist is also not _just_ an insult. That's not what my question is about, though... Any ideas on how I can prevent misunderstanding my question?

Comment: @aross Perhaps people *aren't* misunderstanding, and simply disagree with your position?  If the reviewers/readers feel that the information, while technically insulting, is both accurate and information worth knowing (rather than an insult for the sake of being insulting) and therefore feel that it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @aross Votes on Meta tend to (but not always) express agreement or disagreement with your point rather than the validity or usefulness of your question/answer. My guess is the folks down-voting this question are simply taking the quick route to indicate that they also would disagree with your edit of that particular answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if my answer to this was ...

*Anyone that rejects such an edit also eats kittens for brunch, and eats brunch because they can't possibly wake up on-time after clubbing baby seals all night*

Yeah, you'd be more inclined to simply down-vote it. You could also leave a comment saying you felt the answer was good, but didn't feel it was good for the *site* because of the claim. You could also go on to indicate that you're happy to reverse your vote if the claim was removed.

Sure, editing sort of sends the same signal, but you've got something that someone felt strong enough about to quite deliberately post on a very public site. The answer being a shining example of the culture that we aspire to or not, the edit *did* change the voice and tone of the answer, which is something that only the author should do.

It's hard to apply a *blanket* set of guidelines here, it depends on what someone typed in the answer box.

*Only [racial slur] that [description of something really offensive] does this sort of thing* is a great time to use that 'offensive' button instead of reaching for an edit, because a moderator really needs to see that filth in all its glory so they can launch missiles. If it irritates you but is *not* flag-worthy, think hard about it being edit-worthy.

*Only seriously inept people do this* is a good time to use your down vote and (optionally, without unnecessarily antagonizing the author, explain why you did so).

It's a judgement call that takes a little time to learn. Don't worry so much about a negative *tone* when editing, just make sure that if the answer is down-voted into oblivion, it's not because of the grammar, spelling, lack of paragraph separation, unnecessary formatting, pluralization of a mass noun that is not in-jest and other, you know, *important* stuff.

If you see negativity without any *possibility* of usefulness, flag it and it'll quite likely be vaporized.

Comment: But Kittens are tasty and if I don't club the baby seals who will?

Comment: @Servy The _kittens_, had you not eaten them. Duh.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. Though this answer in particular is 2 years old and already had a comment calling out its offensive nature. I don't think the author really tended to that answer for quite some time, so does the same still apply?

Comment: @aross There's always exceptions to advice or learned wisdom. While your edits still need peer-review yes, changes to the tone or voice of a post in the absence of _glaring_ issues will probably result in the edit being rejected. I don't consider referring to a group as 'Charlatans' as quite _glaring_.  Had you edited it directly (and had the rep to do it), the author would have been notified and _might_ have rolled it back. If they did that, then it's time to just down-vote if you feel strongly, and move on.

Comment: About the phrase, while it's a bit blunter, what if I said "There are a lot of people that read extremely old but well-indexed PHP blogs from 5 years ago, and spread really bad information simply because they don't know any better" - I said the same thing, while I agree the term is pejorative and intentionally so, I _don't_ think it really crosses the line in the context that it was offered.